# While Loop update first Row data only when use with AJAX PHP

Tags: php, ajax

I have a while Loop in my PHP code which fetches data of a post like a poster name, time, etc.
The problem is that when I try to update any data like from client-side, so it only works for the first row That is displayed. This problem only appears when I use AJAX, using simple form do not trigger this problem.

**Real Scenario**: When I Like the first post, everything works fine, but when I like the second post, it mostly doesn't work and sometimes updates data with first post $POST_ID.

Should I prefer to use any other loop or what?

**Index.php**

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$user_id = $row['user_id'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users where id=$user_id";
$results = $connect->query($sql);
$user_d = mysqli_fetch_array($results);
$post_id = $row['post_id'];
$date = strtotime($row['published_at']);
?>

<div class="posts" id="post_<?php echo $row['post_id']?>">
<div class="pd20px">
 <a href="profile.php?id=<?php echo $user_d['id']?>">
   <div class="profile_img_on_post_div">
     <img class="profile_img_on_post" src="<?php echo $user_d['profile_img'] ?>">
   </div>
   <div class="poster_info">
     <b>
       <span>
         <?php echo $user_d['username'] ?>
       </span>
     </b>
     <?php 
if ($user_d['verified'] == 'true') {
?>
     <img src="img/verified.png" alt="Verified User" class="verified_on_post">
     <?php
}
?>
     <span style="font-weight: 400; font-size: 15px; color: #696969">
       <?php if (empty($row['is_this_a_post'])) {
if ($user_d['gender'] == 'male') {
echo ' updated his profile picture.';
}elseif ($user_d['gender'] == 'female') {
echo ' updated her profile picture.';
}
} ?>
     </span>
     <br>
     </a>
   <span style="font-size: 12px; color:#696969 ">
     <?php  echo date('d F, Y' , strtotime($row['published_at'])) ?>
   </span>
   <span style="float: right;">
     <?php 
if ($row['user_id'] == $c_user_id) {                     
?>
     <form method="POST" action="inc/delete_post.php">
       <button class="delete" name="delete" >Delete
       </button>
       <input type="text" name="post_id" hidden="true" value="<?php echo $row['post_id']  ?>">
     </form>
     <?php
}
?>
   </span>
   </div>
</div>
<div>
 <a href="post.php?id=<?php echo $post_id?>">
   <img width="100%" height="auto" src="<?php echo $row['img_location'] ?>">
 </a>
</div>
<div class="post_likes_info">
 <?php 
$result1 = mysqli_query($connect , "SELECT * FROM likes where  post_id=$post_id AND liker_id=$c_user_id");
$already_like = mysqli_num_rows($result1) ;
if ($already_like == 1) { ?>

   <button class="unlikebtn" name="unlike" id="unlike_btn">
     <span class="like_toggle">
       <svg aria-label="Unlike" class="like_ico" fill="#ed4956" height="24" viewBox="0 0 48 48" width="24">
         <path clip-rule="evenodd" d="M35.3 35.6c-9.2 8.2-9.8 8.9-11.3 8.9s-2.1-.7-11.3-8.9C6.5 30.1.5 25.6.5 17.8.5 9.9 6.4 3.5 13.7 3.5 20.8 3.5 24 8.8 24 8.8s3.2-5.3 10.3-5.3c7.3 0 13.2 6.4 13.2 14.3 0 7.8-6.1 12.3-12.2 17.8z" fill-rule="evenodd">
         </path>
       </svg>
     </span>
   </button>
   <input type="text" name="post_id" id="post_u_id" hidden="true" value="<?php echo $post_id ?>">
   <a href="post.php?id=<?php echo $post_id?>">
     <svg aria-label="Comment" class="comment_ico " fill="#262626" height="24" viewBox="0 0 48 48" width="24">
       <path clip-rule="evenodd" d="M47.5 46.1l-2.8-11c1.8-3.3 2.8-7.1 2.8-11.1C47.5 11 37 .5 24 .5S.5 11 .5 24 11 47.5 24 47.5c4 0 7.8-1 11.1-2.8l11 2.8c.8.2 1.6-.6 1.4-1.4zm-3-22.1c0 4-1 7-2.6 10-.2.4-.3.9-.2 1.4l2.1 8.4-8.3-2.1c-.5-.1-1-.1-1.4.2-1.8 1-5.2 2.6-10 2.6-11.4 0-20.6-9.2-20.6-20.5S12.7 3.5 24 3.5 44.5 12.7 44.5 24z" fill-rule="evenodd">
       </path>
     </svg>
   </a>

 <?php } elseif($already_like == 0){  ?>

   <button name="like" class="likebtn" id="like_btn" data-itemID="<?php echo $post_id?>">
     <span class="like_toggle">
       <svg aria-label="Like" class="like_ico" fill="#262626" height="24" viewBox="0 0 48 48" width="24">
         <path clip-rule="evenodd" d="M34.3 3.5C27.2 3.5 24 8.8 24 8.8s-3.2-5.3-10.3-5.3C6.4 3.5.5 9.9.5 17.8s6.1 12.4 12.2 17.8c9.2 8.2 9.8 8.9 11.3 8.9s2.1-.7 11.3-8.9c6.2-5.5 12.2-10 12.2-17.8 0-7.9-5.9-14.3-13.2-14.3zm-1 29.8c-5.4 4.8-8.3 7.5-9.3 8.1-1-.7-4.6-3.9-9.3-8.1-5.5-4.9-11.2-9-11.2-15.6 0-6.2 4.6-11.3 10.2-11.3 4.1 0 6.3 2 7.9 4.2 3.6 5.1 1.2 5.1 4.8 0 1.6-2.2 3.8-4.2 7.9-4.2 5.6 0 10.2 5.1 10.2 11.3 0 6.7-5.7 10.8-11.2 15.6z" fill-rule="evenodd">
         </path>
       </svg>
     </span>
   </button>
   <a href="post.php?id=<?php echo $post_id?>">
     <svg aria-label="Comment" class="comment_ico " fill="#262626" height="24" viewBox="0 0 48 48" width="24">
       <path clip-rule="evenodd" d="M47.5 46.1l-2.8-11c1.8-3.3 2.8-7.1 2.8-11.1C47.5 11 37 .5 24 .5S.5 11 .5 24 11 47.5 24 47.5c4 0 7.8-1 11.1-2.8l11 2.8c.8.2 1.6-.6 1.4-1.4zm-3-22.1c0 4-1 7-2.6 10-.2.4-.3.9-.2 1.4l2.1 8.4-8.3-2.1c-.5-.1-1-.1-1.4.2-1.8 1-5.2 2.6-10 2.6-11.4 0-20.6-9.2-20.6-20.5S12.7 3.5 24 3.5 44.5 12.7 44.5 24z" fill-rule="evenodd">
       </path>
     </svg>
   </a>
   <?php }  ?>
   <input type="text" name="post_id" id="post_u_id" value="<?php echo $post_id ?>">

</div>
<?php $results = mysqli_query($connect , "SELECT * FROM likes where post_id=$post_id");
?>
<span class="like_count">
 <?php echo mysqli_num_rows($results); ?> Likes
</span>
<br>
<span class="poster_name">
 <?php echo $user_d['username']?>
</span>
<span id="poster_description" class="poster_description">
 <?php echo $row['post_text']?>
</span>
<div class="comment">
 <?php 
$r  = mysqli_query($connect , "SELECT * FROM comments where post_id = $post_id ");   
$no_of_cmts =mysqli_num_rows($r) ;
if ( $no_of_cmts > 2) { ?>
 <a href="post.php?id=<?php echo $post_id?>" id="vac">View All 
   <?php echo $no_of_cmts ?> Commnets
 </a>
 <br>
 <?php }
$comments  = mysqli_query($connect , "SELECT * FROM comments where post_id = $post_id limit 2");   
while ( $cmts = $comments->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ 
$commenter_id = $cmts['commenter'];
$user = mysqli_query($connect , "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=$commenter_id");
$users_data = mysqli_fetch_array($user);
?>
 <span class="name_cmt">
   <?php echo $users_data['username'];?> 
 </span>
 <span id="comment_content">
   <?php echo $cmts['comment_content'];?>
 </span>
 <br>

 <?php }
?>
 <?php 
include_once "inc/time.php";
$time = $row['published_at'];?>
 <span class="time"> 
   <?php echo time_elapsed_string($time); ?>
 </span>

   <div class="add_a_comment">

       <div class="add_comment_section">
         <span class="hor-line">
         </span>
         <div>
           <textarea contenteditable aria-label="Add a comment…" placeholder="Add a comment…" class="addcomment_ta" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" id="comment_content" name="comment_content" id="editable_comment">
           </textarea>
         </div>
         <div class="post_btn">
           <button  id="btn_comment" >POST
           </button>
         </div>
       </div>
       <input type="text" name="post_id" id="post_id" hidden="true" value="<?php echo $row['post_id']  ?>">

   </div>
   </div>
</div>

<br>
<?php     
}
echo "<h2 class=\"center\" style=\"margin-bottom:10px;\">No More Post Found :(</h2>";
?>
```

**AJAX**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#btn_comment").click(function(){
            $.post("inc/add_comment.php" , 
            {
                comment_content:$("#comment_content").val(),
                post_id:$("#post_id").val()

            },
            function(data){
                alert("data");
            })

        });
    });
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#like_btn").click(function(){
             itemID = $(this).data("itemID");
            $.post("inc/like.php" , 
            {
                post_u_id:itemID

            },
            function(data){
            })

        });
    });
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#unlike_btn").click(function(){
            $.post("inc/unlike.php" , 
            {
                post_id:$("#post_u_id").val()


            },
            function(data){
            })

        });
    });
```

**Like.php**

```
    <?php 
    session_start();
    include 'db.php';
    $id=$_SESSION['c_user_id'];
        $results = mysqli_query($connect , "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=$id");
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($results);
        $c_user_id = $row['id'];
        $post_u_id = $_POST['post_u_id'];
        $result = mysqli_query($connect , "INSERT INTO likes (liker_id , post_id ) VALUES ('$c_user_id ', '$post_u_id')");
        echo "done";

     ?>
```

Comment: Are you attempting to assign the same `id` such as `like_btn` to multiple buttons? This is not allowed; `$('#like_btn')` will always refer to the first button with that id.

Comment: HI, thanks for replying. I am not using multiple buttons with same id but in a loop, it will absolutely be more than one as the loop goes on. So what should I do?

Comment: Forget about assigning id attributes to your like and dislike buttons. Change your button `click` handlers to use the button classes instead, for example: `$(".likebtn").click(function(){`. This should assign a click handler for *all* the buttons that specify `class="likebtn"`. You may have, of course, other problems, but this one seems obvious.

Comment: Thanks, It almost solved half of the problem but now post_id is being taken of the first post in the loop every time as it's in the loop so the first value, so any help here?

Comment: I see now there is also in your unlike button handler: `post_id:$("#post_u_id").val()`. This will require more than just a comment ...

Comment: Bro Don't get into the whole code as it's so messy and unmanaged. I hope you will help me. If you want, you can study the code and help me solve the problem. Actually the problem is just For classes and Id Attribute as i am very new to Php and AJAX combo so i'm little bit confused!Thanks Again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the general idea. I don't know if I caught all the problems.

What if instead of:

```
if ($already_like == 1) { ?>

<button class="unlikebtn" name="unlike" id="unlike_btn">
  <span class="like_toggle">
    <svg aria-label="Unlike" class="like_ico" fill="#ed4956" height="24" viewBox="0 0 48 48" width="24">
      <path clip-rule="evenodd" d="M35.3 35.6c-9.2 8.2-9.8 8.9-11.3 8.9s-2.1-.7-11.3-8.9C6.5 30.1.5 25.6.5 17.8.5 9.9 6.4 3.5 13.7 3.5 20.8 3.5 24 8.8 24 8.8s3.2-5.3 10.3-5.3c7.3 0 13.2 6.4 13.2 14.3 0 7.8-6.1 12.3-12.2 17.8z" fill-rule="evenodd">
      </path>
    </svg>
  </span>
</button>
<input type="text" name="post_id" id="post_u_id" hidden="true" value="<?php echo $post_id ?>">
<a href="post.php?id=<?php echo $post_id?>">
  <svg aria-label="Comment" class="comment_ico " fill="#262626" height="24" viewBox="0 0 48 48" width="24">
    <path clip-rule="evenodd" d="M47.5 46.1l-2.8-11c1.8-3.3 2.8-7.1 2.8-11.1C47.5 11 37 .5 24 .5S.5 11 .5 24 11 47.5 24 47.5c4 0 7.8-1 11.1-2.8l11 2.8c.8.2 1.6-.6 1.4-1.4zm-3-22.1c0 4-1 7-2.6 10-.2.4-.3.9-.2 1.4l2.1 8.4-8.3-2.1c-.5-.1-1-.1-1.4.2-1.8 1-5.2 2.6-10 2.6-11.4 0-20.6-9.2-20.6-20.5S12.7 3.5 24 3.5 44.5 12.7 44.5 24z" fill-rule="evenodd">
    </path>
  </svg>
</a>

 <?php } elseif($already_like == 0){  ?>

   <button name="like" class="likebtn" id="like_btn" data-itemID="<?php echo $post_id?>">
     <span class="like_toggle">
       <svg aria-label="Like" class="like_ico" fill="#262626" height="24" viewBox="0 0 48 48" width="24">
         <path clip-rule="evenodd" d="M34.3 3.5C27.2 3.5 24 8.8 24 8.8s-3.2-5.3-10.3-5.3C6.4 3.5.5 9.9.5 17.8s6.1 12.4 12.2 17.8c9.2 8.2 9.8 8.9 11.3 8.9s2.1-.7 11.3-8.9c6.2-5.5 12.2-10 12.2-17.8 0-7.9-5.9-14.3-13.2-14.3zm-1 29.8c-5.4 4.8-8.3 7.5-9.3 8.1-1-.7-4.6-3.9-9.3-8.1-5.5-4.9-11.2-9-11.2-15.6 0-6.2 4.6-11.3 10.2-11.3 4.1 0 6.3 2 7.9 4.2 3.6 5.1 1.2 5.1 4.8 0 1.6-2.2 3.8-4.2 7.9-4.2 5.6 0 10.2 5.1 10.2 11.3 0 6.7-5.7 10.8-11.2 15.6z" fill-rule="evenodd">
         </path>
       </svg>
     </span>
   </button>
   <a href="post.php?id=<?php echo $post_id?>">
     <svg aria-label="Comment" class="comment_ico " fill="#262626" height="24" viewBox="0 0 48 48" width="24">
       <path clip-rule="evenodd" d="M47.5 46.1l-2.8-11c1.8-3.3 2.8-7.1 2.8-11.1C47.5 11 37 .5 24 .5S.5 11 .5 24 11 47.5 24 47.5c4 0 7.8-1 11.1-2.8l11 2.8c.8.2 1.6-.6 1.4-1.4zm-3-22.1c0 4-1 7-2.6 10-.2.4-.3.9-.2 1.4l2.1 8.4-8.3-2.1c-.5-.1-1-.1-1.4.2-1.8 1-5.2 2.6-10 2.6-11.4 0-20.6-9.2-20.6-20.5S12.7 3.5 24 3.5 44.5 12.7 44.5 24z" fill-rule="evenodd">
       </path>
     </svg>
   </a>
   <?php }  ?>
```

and

```
<div class="add_a_comment">

    <div class="add_comment_section">
      <span class="hor-line">
      </span>
      <div>
        <textarea contenteditable aria-label="Add a comment…" placeholder="Add a comment…" class="addcomment_ta" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" id="comment_content" name="comment_content" id="editable_comment">
        </textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="post_btn">
        <button  id="btn_comment" >POST
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="text" name="post_id" id="post_id" hidden="true" value="<?php echo $row['post_id']  ?>">

</div>
```

We get rid of the hidden input tag that holds the `$post_id` and instead use that as the `id` for the button:

```
if ($already_like == 1) { ?>

<button class="unlikebtn" name="unlike" id="<?php echo $post_id ?>">
  <span class="like_toggle">
    <svg aria-label="Unlike" class="like_ico" fill="#ed4956" height="24" viewBox="0 0 48 48" width="24">
      <path clip-rule="evenodd" d="M35.3 35.6c-9.2 8.2-9.8 8.9-11.3 8.9s-2.1-.7-11.3-8.9C6.5 30.1.5 25.6.5 17.8.5 9.9 6.4 3.5 13.7 3.5 20.8 3.5 24 8.8 24 8.8s3.2-5.3 10.3-5.3c7.3 0 13.2 6.4 13.2 14.3 0 7.8-6.1 12.3-12.2 17.8z" fill-rule="evenodd">
      </path>
    </svg>
  </span>
</button>
?>">
<a href="post.php?id=<?php echo $post_id?>">
  <svg aria-label="Comment" class="comment_ico " fill="#262626" height="24" viewBox="0 0 48 48" width="24">
    <path clip-rule="evenodd" d="M47.5 46.1l-2.8-11c1.8-3.3 2.8-7.1 2.8-11.1C47.5 11 37 .5 24 .5S.5 11 .5 24 11 47.5 24 47.5c4 0 7.8-1 11.1-2.8l11 2.8c.8.2 1.6-.6 1.4-1.4zm-3-22.1c0 4-1 7-2.6 10-.2.4-.3.9-.2 1.4l2.1 8.4-8.3-2.1c-.5-.1-1-.1-1.4.2-1.8 1-5.2 2.6-10 2.6-11.4 0-20.6-9.2-20.6-20.5S12.7 3.5 24 3.5 44.5 12.7 44.5 24z" fill-rule="evenodd">
    </path>
  </svg>
</a>

 <?php } elseif($already_like == 0){  ?>

   <button name="like" class="likebtn" id="<?php echo $post_id?>">
     <span class="like_toggle">
       <svg aria-label="Like" class="like_ico" fill="#262626" height="24" viewBox="0 0 48 48" width="24">
         <path clip-rule="evenodd" d="M34.3 3.5C27.2 3.5 24 8.8 24 8.8s-3.2-5.3-10.3-5.3C6.4 3.5.5 9.9.5 17.8s6.1 12.4 12.2 17.8c9.2 8.2 9.8 8.9 11.3 8.9s2.1-.7 11.3-8.9c6.2-5.5 12.2-10 12.2-17.8 0-7.9-5.9-14.3-13.2-14.3zm-1 29.8c-5.4 4.8-8.3 7.5-9.3 8.1-1-.7-4.6-3.9-9.3-8.1-5.5-4.9-11.2-9-11.2-15.6 0-6.2 4.6-11.3 10.2-11.3 4.1 0 6.3 2 7.9 4.2 3.6 5.1 1.2 5.1 4.8 0 1.6-2.2 3.8-4.2 7.9-4.2 5.6 0 10.2 5.1 10.2 11.3 0 6.7-5.7 10.8-11.2 15.6z" fill-rule="evenodd">
         </path>
       </svg>
     </span>
   </button>
   <a href="post.php?id=<?php echo $post_id?>">
     <svg aria-label="Comment" class="comment_ico " fill="#262626" height="24" viewBox="0 0 48 48" width="24">
       <path clip-rule="evenodd" d="M47.5 46.1l-2.8-11c1.8-3.3 2.8-7.1 2.8-11.1C47.5 11 37 .5 24 .5S.5 11 .5 24 11 47.5 24 47.5c4 0 7.8-1 11.1-2.8l11 2.8c.8.2 1.6-.6 1.4-1.4zm-3-22.1c0 4-1 7-2.6 10-.2.4-.3.9-.2 1.4l2.1 8.4-8.3-2.1c-.5-.1-1-.1-1.4.2-1.8 1-5.2 2.6-10 2.6-11.4 0-20.6-9.2-20.6-20.5S12.7 3.5 24 3.5 44.5 12.7 44.5 24z" fill-rule="evenodd">
       </path>
     </svg>
   </a>
   <?php }  ?>
```

and we create a form with a name for adding a comment so that we can get the value of the post id using `document.add_comment.post_id.value`:

```
<div class="add_a_comment">
    <div class="add_comment_section">
      <span class="hor-line">
      </span>
      <div>
        <form name="add_comment">
          <textarea contenteditable aria-label="Add a comment…" placeholder="Add a comment…" class="addcomment_ta" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" id="comment_content" name="comment_content" id="editable_comment">
          </textarea>
          <div class="post_btn">
            <id="btn_comment">POST</button>
          </div>
          <input type="text" name="post_id" hidden="true" value="<?php echo $row['post_id']  ?>">
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then the JavaScript becomes:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn_comment").click(function(){
        $.post("inc/add_comment.php" , 
        {
            comment_content: $("#comment_content").val(),
            post_id: document.add_comment.post_id.value
        },
        function(data){
            alert("data");
        })

    });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".likebtn").click(function() {
        let post_u_id = $(this).attr('id');
        $.post("inc/like.php", 
        {
            post_u_id: post_u_id
        },
        function(data){
        })
    });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".unlikebtn").click(function() {
        let post_u_id = $(this).attr('id');
        $.post("inc/unlike.php", 
        {
            post_id: post_u_id
        },
        function(data){
        })
    });
});
```

**Suggestion**

You are currently using AJAX to delete, update and add comments. But you are neglecting to update the presentation (the `DOM`) on return from a successful AJAX call. For example, on a successful delete of a comment you should be removing the comment from the `DOM`. If a comment is "unliked", it should now be shown as an unliked comment. Since you are not doing any of this, it would be better *not* to be using AJAX at all and to just instead create forms like the following:

You should reorganizing your HTML so that you create forms for each comment. An example:

```
<form action="inc/unlike.php" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="<?php echo $post_id ?>">
  <button type="submit">
    <span class="like_toggle">
      <svg aria-label="Unlike" class="like_ico" fill="#ed4956" height="24" viewBox="0 0 48 48" width="24">
        <path clip-rule="evenodd" d="M35.3 35.6c-9.2 8.2-9.8 8.9-11.3 8.9s-2.1-.7-11.3-8.9C6.5 30.1.5 25.6.5 17.8.5 9.9 6.4 3.5 13.7 3.5 20.8 3.5 24 8.8 24 8.8s3.2-5.3 10.3-5.3c7.3 0 13.2 6.4 13.2 14.3 0 7.8-6.1 12.3-12.2 17.8z" fill-rule="evenodd">
        </path>
      </svg>
    </span>
  </button>
</form>
```

Your `unlike.php` script would then complete by redirecting back to `index.php` to recreate an updated presentation.

Comment: A huge thanks Brother. You really did very well resolving the issue. Just mentioning. i found another solution With Data-id Attr. but thats not much secure. Also thanks for the suggestion, but i'm going to delete, update fields now as my problem is resolved..I was using forms back before and the forms were working great but ware refreshing page thats why i converted to AJAX and whole problem got in. Thanks Again. 

Comment: Yes, I saw that and perhaps using that is better. But you can do either `$('some-selector').attr('data-id')` or `$('some-selector').data('id')`. The first version will always return a string and the second *might* convert it into some other type, for example a `Number`,  if it can depending on the value. That may be a good thing, a bad thing or it doesn't matter. Just be aware.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for this too. You actually resoved almost all my issue. One last question a little off topic.You see my code, its all messy and unmanaged. Mean i've concatenated all php in Html. So is there anyway doing better than this atleast making it to sell commercially or any other method or reference . Thanks Again.

Comment: You need to separate business logic from presentation. You should investigate the `MVC` or Model-View-Controller paradigm (or design pattern). There are any number of frameworks, some rather lightweight, for doing this.

Comment: Hi thanks for assisting me. You really Helped me a lot. You are a life saviour! 